# Gradle shared dependency version issue

Tags: java, gradle

I have an issue with the wrong version of a dependency that is taken by Gradle build. I use Gradle 4.6.

I have a library that I develop which brings Utils king of features. Let's call it utils.jar.
I also develop another library for communication with a webservice. Let's call it network.jar.
Then I develop a project where I need network.jar dependency and utils.jar dependency. But I need a utils.jar version that is higher than the one used by network.jar.

```
My project 
 |
 |-> network.jar:v1
 |       |
 |       |
 |       -> utils.jar:v1
 |
 -> utils.jar:v2
```

Here is the build.gradle for network library

```
dependencies {   
    compile "com.mycompany:utils:1"
}
```

Here is the build.gradle for my project

```
dependencies {   
    compile "com.mycompany:network:1" // pull utils.jar:1
    compile "com.mycompany:utils:2" // I need utils.jar:2 in my project
}
```

With that in my project, when I try to use the v2 of utils.jar, the new method introduced in v2 are not available. In IntelliJ, I can see utils.jar v2 in the classpath but when I try to use com.mycompany.utils.CollectionUtils class for example, it uses the utils code embedded in network.jar library (v1) instead of using the code of utils v2.

So I tried to explicitly remove utils.jar (v1) from network.jar while this dependency is imported in my project. build.gradle in my project :

```
dependencies {   
    compile("com.mycompany:network:1") {
        exclude group: 'com.mycompany', module: 'utils' 
    }
    compile "com.mycompany:utils:2"
}
```

But the utils v1 code is still embedded in the network.jar code and this is the one that is used instead of v2.

How can I make Gradle understand that I want utils v2 and not utils v1 that is pulled by network.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I was building and publishing on Maven repo the network.jar lib as a fat-jar. Consequently, the code of utils.jar was always embedded in the code of network.jar.

In case people does the same mistake, I post the solution.

I removed this from the network.jar build.gradle file :

```
jar {
    // Remove that to not build a fat-jar in this case
    // from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Utils',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Created-By': 'Myself'
    }
}
```